# Inflection of fraction numerals of per cents with nouns (в 2,4 процента? -ах? случаев)

Tags: падежи, числительные, inflection

I'm a bit puzzled as to the correct inflection of the word **процент** in a phrase such as

> в 2,4 процент(?) случаев

Grammatically in the fractional part of fraction numerals **процент** must be inflected in singular Genitive - **4 десятых процента**. But then the phrase in question would sound a little odd

> в двух целых, четырёх десятых процентА случаев

because **процент** is preceded by all words with flexions ending with "**X**" and kind of awkwardly stands out.

So is this correct or should it instead be changed into ungrammatical but euphonically preferable

> в двух целых, четырёх десятых процентАХ случаев

Answer (score 1):

[numeralonline.ru: *Склонение дробных числительных*](http://numeralonline.ru/#fractional)

> Склонение дробных числительных
>   Примеры дробных числительных: одна вторая, семь сотых, полтора.
>   Дробное числительное состоит из двух частей: числитель дроби (количественное числительное, обозначающее целое число) и знаменатель дроби (порядковое числительное). Если числитель заканчивается на цифру «один», то вместо неё используется «одна». Цифра «два» заменяется на «две». Сравните: одна пятая, две пятых, три пятых, четыре пятых.
>
> Изменяются по падежам обе части в соответствии со склонением количественных и порядковых числительных. Знаменатель склоняется как порядковое числительное во множественном числе: к трем пятым (д.п.), с двумя пятыми (тв.п.). Или как порядковое числительное в единственном числе женского рода, если числитель оканчивается на 1: к одной пятой, вижу двадцать одну тридцать седьмую. При обозначении количества существительное при дробном числительном употребляется в родительном падеже: от одной седьмой участка, к двум седьмым площади прямоугольника.

See also: [licey.net: *Некоторые особенности согласования*](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/783-33_nekotorye_osobennosti_soglasovaniya.html).

[evartist.narod.ru: *п.8*](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm):

> Правильными являются конструкции 35,5 процента (не ...процентов), 12,6 километра (не ...километров), т.е. при смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число. Также: 45,0 (сорок пять и ноль десятых) секунды, 67/8 (шесть и семь восьмых) метра и т.п.

[school-assistant.ru](http://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=drobnie_chislitelnie):

> Порядковое числительное в обозначениях дробных чисел
>   употребляется в форме Р.п. мн. числа: три четвёртых, шесть восьмых.
>   Существительные при сочетаниях, обозначающих дробные числа,
>   употребляются в форме Р. п. ед. числа: две третьих часа, пять сотых грамма.

---

Получается, что правильно так:

> в 2,4 процент**а** случаев

Comment: in theory yes, here's a list of answers to relevant questions from [Gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C&limitstart=0), the problem with the questions is that all of them give examples in Nominal case of which just a couple address phrases similar to mine, and of those only one is in oblique case (Accusative) which inflects as Nominative anyway so isn't of much help because the problem of euphony doesn't become apparent